# Accepting templated arguments in function signature regardless of actual instantiation

Tags: c++, templates

the title may be a bit confusing so let me elaborate.

Say, I have a class `template<bool is_const> foo` that can take one of two forms, const or non-const based on the template parameter. This class has some operators overloaded like

```
bool foo<is_const>::operator==(const foo<is_const> &other) const {
    return this->a == other.a;
}
```

The actual return value is irrelevant here. The point is I have quite a few of those operators and for none of them does it really matter what the value of `is_const` is for either of the two operands. So, I would like to avoid having to duplicate each operator (once for `is_bool==true` and once for `is_bool==false`). Is it possible to define the function in a way that it doesn't really matter what value `is_bool` has? Kind of like `const foo<> &other` (which doesn't work, I tried that).

Comment: Wouldmit be possible to find a non template base class?

Comment: It would, but I really do want to avoid the virtual function call overhead... Any soluton without inheritance would be greatly preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the operator a template:

```
template <bool B>
bool operator==(const foo<B> & other) const
{
    return a = other.a;
}
```

As you discovered, it is generally preferable to have operator overloads be non-member functions, possibly friends:

```
template <bool A, bool B>
friend bool operator==(const foo<A> & lhs, const foo<B> & rhs)
{
    return lhs.a == rhs.a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can have template method:

```
template<bool is_const> 
class foo {
public:
   template<bool is_another_const>
   bool operator==( const foo<is_another_const> &other ) const;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to both of you, @kerek-sb and @slava. Even though your answers didn't really solve the problem it pushed me in the right direction.

The problem with your solutions is that `&other` is not necessarily the same class as `this` any more and thus has no access to private members, which is unfortunately crucial for the comparison operators to work. So I played around with making the function a `friend`. What I arrived at is this:

```
template <bool lhs_const, bool rhs_const>
friend bool operator==(const _Iterator<lhs_const>& lhs, const _Iterator<rhs_const>& rhs) {
    return (lhs.m_pos == rhs.m_pos) && (lhs.m_buffer == rhs.m_buffer);
}
```

The `friend` keyword gives access to private members for both template instantiations. It's not technically a member function any more but that doesn't really matter much.